# How to draw Focus Border to a specific Tab in MFC TabControl

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, tabcontrol, ctabctrl

I was trying to Manually Set Focus border to Tabs selected using [`SetCurSel()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ctabctrl-class?view=msvc-160#setcursel) API. But While doing so i also wanted to set the Keyboard Focus(Dotted Border Focus around the Tab as shown in Picture). All I could achieve is Tab selection using `SetCurSel()`.

[image: Focus Border Applied to Tab Control when in Keyboard Focus]
In my project I don't want the `TCN_SELCHANGING` to be send, that's why I'm using `SetCurSel()` instead of [`SetCurFocus()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ctabctrl-class?view=msvc-160#setcurfocus) which will invoke `TCN_SELCHANGING` or `TCN_SELCHANGE` notification message.

Currently in my code I am overriding `LBUTTON` down message to take control of Tab Selection and and I would call `SetCurSel()` from there.

```
LRESULT TabEx::WindowProc( UINT uMsg_i, WPARAM wParam_i, LPARAM lParam_i )
{
    switch( uMsg_i )
    {
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN :
        {
            switch( wParam_i )
            {
                case MK_LBUTTON:
                {
                    int nIndex = GetCurSel( );
                    if()// Logic To determine Which Tab to Select
                    {
                            // Decide to Select nIndex th Tab
                            SetCurSel( nIndex );
                            SendSelChangeNotification( TCN_SELCHANGE );
                            retrun true;
                    
                    }
                    
                    break;
                }
            }
        break;
        }
        .
        .
        .
        .
    }
    .
    .
                            
}
```

The issue with the above code is it will change the tab selection but No Focus in changed. I cannot use [`SetCurFocus()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ctabctrl-class?view=msvc-160#setcurfocus) here since I don't want to interfere with `TCN_SELCHANGING`. Is there any direct Message call or function call to Set the Focus to a specific Tab?

Comment: *"I was trying to Manually Set Focus border to Tabs selected using `SetCurSel()` API."* - Why? What *problem* are you trying to solve? Are you sure that this isn't an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info)?

Comment: Anyway, the function is unsurprisingly called [DrawFocusRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawfocusrect). Using it properly is far more involved than it looks.

Comment: My intent was to remove the offset [offset space](https://imgur.com/a/mFTH7zE) that is found to left of first Tab in Tab Control. I was able to remove that by drawing custom Tab and modifying the Tab Width using Deflate rectangle. I was successful in removing that offset GUI wise but the API's GetCurSel() and HitTest() returned Tab Indices without accounting for the offset i just removed.  @IInspectable